# Promise returned from redux-saga yield instead of value

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux-saga

I have a redux-saga function like below that yields for another function to read Firebase to get a value

```
export function* inventoryTransaction(action) {
  const { locationId, parts } = action;

  yield all(
    parts.map(part =>
      call(adjustInventoryQuantity, locationId, part)
    )
  );
}

function* adjustInventoryQuantity(locationId, part) {
  const { partId, qty } = part;

  const quantity = yield call(getPartQuantity, locationId, partId);

  // ...do something with quantity here
}

function* getPartQuantity(locationId, partId) {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`locations/${locationId}/parts/${partId}/qty`)
    .once("value")
    .then(snapShot => snapShot.val());
}
```

However, `const quantity = yield call(getPartQuantity, locationId, partId)`, quantity is always assigned a promise, even though I am returning snapShot.val(). What do I need to adjust so that getPartQuantity actually returns the snapShot value (the quantity)?

Comment: getPartQuantity should not be a generator function. You don't yield from it. Try changing `function* getPartQuantity` to `function getPartQuantity`.

Comment: Hey thanks, that works. I am still introducing myself to redux-saga and generator functions in general. From my reading, yielding inside a generator function pauses the saga execution until the promise resolves. I see why getPartQuantity does not need to be a generator function now since nothing yields from it, but let's say I make a call to Firebase to write the quantity in the `...do something with quantity here` section of the code above. Would I need to yield this Firebase call? Or do you *only* yield when you need to pause for a function to execute before continuing?

Comment: It's possible to call functions inside sagas directly, without using `yield call(...`, but you shouldn't do it. That would block all your sagas while waiting for the promise to resolve. Also it makes unit testing impossible. (I'm not an expert on coroutines, so other people can probably explain this better)